# How to shared open cart session in multiple domains

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I have a Moodle website and an Opencart website, I want to share Opencart session data with the Moodle website.

How would I do this?

Comment: what is your actual opencart version ?

Comment: opencart version - 3.0.3.2

Answer (score 0):

See if you're going to use session for two different websites and I am assuming these both websites are deployed on different servers then do checkout Redis for the same. You can go through this article on [Redis Session Management](https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/use-cases/session-management/). It is better than Database or File storage and you can scale up easily in case of large traffics.